# Mousepad firing too many "wheel" events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll, underscore.js

I'm trying to detect "wheel" events on a web page to intercept these and implement a page-by-page scroll instead.

This works fine with a mouse - using the wheel seems to trigger a single "wheel" event, which I'm able to intercept.

I have an issue with mousepad however, which seems to fire multiple successive "wheel" events. I have tried throttling my custom scroll function using underscoreJS and disabling trailing end, but somehow the subsequent events are still fired..

```
wheelHandlerThrottled: _.throttle(function(e, pageNum) {
  // My scrolling code
}, 500, {leading: true, trailing: false})
```

When on page 1 and scrolling down with mousepad, I'll get the following behavior:

Scroll to page 2
500 ms pause
Scroll to page 3
500 ms pause
Scroll to page 4

Logging events in the console shows me that 3 "wheel" events are fired and processed.. so it's like my throttling is not working, but instead a pause is inserted between every event.

Answer (score 1):

Throttle seems to just pile on the scroll events.

I would do it with something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vewqa63r/12/)

Essentialy a event listener for mousewheel and when its triggered there is a timeout for x miliseconds until it can be triggered again.

```
let canScroll = true;
let marginTop = 10;
const element = $('#custom');
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', (event) => {
    if (canScroll) {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      marginTop += 10;
    } else {
      marginTop -= 10;
    }
    element.css('margin-top', marginTop + 'px');
    canScroll = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      canScroll = true;
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vajura. I tried implementing a similar code, the issues persists, and seems to arise from the way events are fired when using the trackpad: to simulate deceleration of scrolling, several events are fired subsequently, with a decreasing deltaY. So even by giving a small impulsion on the trackpad and throttling by 1000ms, I still end up with events being fired up to 2-3 seconds after the initial touch, because of this deceleration. Any idea on how I could just cancel all the subsequent events after the first one?

Comment: Ah i understand, thats a bit harder to solve. Limit delta to be above a specific value, and a bigger timeout