# How to put a delay on the "wheel" event?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

So I have this code that upon using a mouse wheel or a touchpad changes the view to the next div in the array of sections. However, when I use the touchpad it does not work properly since at every scroll the index changes. How can I add a delay so that every usage of mouse wheel or touchpad is counted as one scroll. Any suggestions ?

```
const MainNavigation = () => {
  let index = 0;
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      --index;
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      ++index;
    }
    scrollToSection();
  });
  const scrollToSection = () => {
    if (index < 0 || index > 2) {
      index = 0;
    }
    console.log(index);
    sections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
};
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=debounce+wheel+event+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How implement debounce for event listener ? Problem with storage event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035360/how-implement-debounce-for-event-listener-problem-with-storage-event)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574747/mousepad-firing-too-many-wheel-events-in-javascript

Comment: Basically: add `setTimeout` that will be cancelled on every too fast even call

Answer (score -1):

```js
let sum = 0
div1.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
   console.log(e.deltaY)
   sum += e.deltaY
   div2.scrollTo(0, Math.floor(sum / 100) * 100)
})

let sum3 = 0;
div3.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   console.log(e.deltaY)
   sum3 += e.deltaY
   div3.scrollTo(0, Math.floor(sum3 / 100) * 100)
})
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
[h100] {
  height: 100px;
}
[w100] {
  width: 100px;
}
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<div h100 w100> 100 </div>
<div h100 w100> 200 </div>
<div h100 w100> 300 </div>
<div h100 w100> 400 </div>
<div h100 w100> 500 </div>
<div h100 w100> 600 </div>
<div h100 w100> 700 </div>
<div h100 w100> 800 </div>
<div h100 w100> 900 </div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<div h100 w100> 100 </div>
<div h100 w100> 200 </div>
<div h100 w100> 300 </div>
<div h100 w100> 400 </div>
<div h100 w100> 500 </div>
<div h100 w100> 600 </div>
<div h100 w100> 700 </div>
<div h100 w100> 800 </div>
<div h100 w100> 900 </div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<div h100 w100> 100 </div>
<div h100 w100> 200 </div>
<div h100 w100> 300 </div>
<div h100 w100> 400 </div>
<div h100 w100> 500 </div>
<div h100 w100> 600 </div>
<div h100 w100> 700 </div>
<div h100 w100> 800 </div>
<div h100 w100> 900 </div>
</div>
```